# How can you output HTML as entities in Twig?

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-2.1

I have widget examples that I need to output the HTML of so that people can copy and paste them onto their own websites. How can I escape the output so that it doesn't get rendered?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up doing this, the key to the problem is using the escape filter as a block, the rest accounts for need for no spaces around `<pre/><code/>`'s to get the desired output:

```
<pre>
    {%- spaceless -%}
        <code>
            {%- filter escape -%}
                {% spaceless %}
                    {% include 'ACMEDemoBundle:Example:widget.html.twig' %}
                {% endspaceless %}
            {%- endfilter -%}
        </code>
    {%- endspaceless -%}
</pre>
```